# No property or association found for [ProtocolSAPGUI] when running Ranorex/Neoload test

Tags: c#, ranorex, neoload

My current test structure is as follows:

```
Smoke_test
    NL_ConnectToDesignAPI
    NL_CreateProject
    NL_StartRecording
    OpenApp
```

All my variables are bound, and the test runs fine until I get to the end of the StartRecording module, when I get the following error displayed in the .rxlog:

> One or more errors occurred. No property or association found for [ProtocolSAPGUI].

I'm not sure what to do, as I've referenced everything in Ranorex, and I'm not sure what ProtocolSAPGUI is referring to. I can't find it being referenced anywhere in the Neoload modules, although I think it is linked to some of the Neoload package dependencies, i.e. the SAP and Simple.OData.Client packages.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem thanks to some help from the Neoload community site.

I was using Neoload version 6.3.0, whereas some of the packages I was using didn't support versions of Neoload older than 6.6.0.

For those using Ranorex/Neoload plugin, you should use Neoload version 6.6.0 to ensure compatibility with the Neoload plugin and its dependencies.